# I try to build my app with docker-compose.yml and it asks for Dockerfile, even if it is never specified

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to deploy a personal project on my personal Fedora server. This is the docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: db
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 1234
      POSTGRES_DB: TESAF
    ports:
      - "9111:5432"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "TESAF"]
  java:
    image: openjdk:19
    container_name: backend
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/app
    command: ["java", "-jar", "/app/TESAF-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
    depends_on:
      postgres:
        condition: service_healthy
  apache:
    image: httpd
    container_name: frontend
    ports:
      - "3000:80"
      - "4443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs
```

The backend folder contains the jar file from the spring application, after building with maven. The frontend folder is the "build" folder produced by react after running `npm run build`. On my MacBook it works fine, yet, when I try to run `sudo docker-compose up`(it gives permissions error without sudo and without the hyphen it says `'compose' is not a docker command`), it gives the following output:

```
Status: Downloaded newer image for postgres:latest
Building java
DEPRECATED: The legacy builder is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
            Install the buildx component to build images with BuildKit:
            https://docs.docker.com/go/buildx/

unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /home/antoniu/tesaf-deploy/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
ERROR: Service 'java' failed to build : Build failed
```

Why does it try to access a Dockerfile that does not exist and is never specified? Is it because I tried running with docker-compose, rather than docker compose? If so, what can I do for it to recognize docker compose?

File structure:

```
./docker-compose.yml
./frontend/<the contents of the build folder or react>
./backend/<the contents of the target folder from maven>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

> When a build subsection is present for a service, Compose ignores the image attribute for the corresponding service, as Compose can build an image from source.

Since you have specified build subsection, docker compose tries to build from the source. To do this, it searches the context folder, `.`, for a Dockerfile, but fails.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the

```
build .
```

from the `java` service in your docker compose file. I believe it is looking for the dockerfile inside your directory because of that.

The docker compose command is: `docker-compose` and not docker compose

Comment: *"The docker compose command is: docker-compose and not docker compose"* Depends on which version of docker you are using. https://docs.docker.com/compose/migrate/

Answer (score 0):

You have specified both an `image` name and a `build` context:

```
  java:
    image: openjdk:19
    container_name: backend
    build: .
```

As others have pointed out, when you have a `build` context, compose looks for a Dockerfile in that context to build the image. When you also have an `image` attribute, compose will give the built image the specified name.

This can be confusing as the `image` tag completely changes meaning when you have a `build` tag present. *Without* the build tag, compose will run the image with the `image` name. *With* the build tag, compose will build an image and name it with the specified name.

When you specify both, you never want to use a name used by another image. When you use `openjdk:19`, you'll 'overwrite' the `openjdk:19` tag on your docker host, so if you later on ask for the `openjdk:19` image, you won't get the public image from Docker Hub. You'll get the image you built yourself. And that can be *really* confusing.

Since you want to run the public `openjdk:19` image and not a custom image, you should delete the `build` tag.

If you wanted to build your own image, you could either skip naming the image by deleting the `image` tag. Or choose a 'private' name that doesn't conflict with public image names. You'd also need to provide a Dockerfile.